# How can i calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}((n+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-n^{\frac{1}{3}})}$

Tags: limits

How can i calculate it?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}((n+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-n^{\frac{1}{3}})}$$

I don't have idea how to do it..

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

Rationalize the numerator

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Then divide numerator & denominator by $n^{2/3}$

Comment: Can you explain what you mean while you say  "Then divide numerator & denominator by n2/3" ?

Comment: @MasterQuestion, After rationalization, what do we have?

Answer (score -2):

Let $n=\frac1t$ then  $${n^{\frac{2}{3}}((n+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-n^{\frac{1}{3}})} ={t^{-\frac{2}{3}}((\frac1t+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-t^{-\frac{1}{3}})} = \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+2t}-1}{t}$$
Hence, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}((n+2)^{\frac{1}{3}}-n^{\frac{1}{3}})} =\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(1+2t)^{1/3}-1}{t} =\left((1+2t)^{1/3}\right)'\bigg|_{t =0} = 2/3 $$